# Plotting output in two columns beside each other from a for loop

Tags: plotting, column

How can I have the output plots in two columns instead of having the plots in a sequence? Like the following:

[[image: Like this]]

Comment: Could you elaborate? It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: @E.Doroskevic When you are plotting in a for loop, the plots appear in a sequence one after another. I wants to have them in two columns.

Comment: `GraphicsGrid@ConstantArray[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}], {2, 2}]`

Answer (score 2):

**Example:**

```
(*Arbitrary data*)
data = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, #}] & /@ (# & /@ Range[2, 5, 1])

(*Process*)
GraphicsGrid @ {GraphicsColumn @ # & /@ Partition[# & /@ data, 2]}
```

**Output:**

[image: Output]

**References**

[# @ & /@](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/25616#25616)
[GraphicsGrid](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphicsGrid.html)
[GraphicsColumn](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphicsColumn.html)
[Partition](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Partition.html)

Comment: Please use an arbitrary for loop.

Comment: E. Doroskevic's answer is the right one. Please imitate it to accomplish your task.

Comment: @bills thank you for acknowledgement!